# To prevent querying or ignore system objects in apex

Tags: apex, soql

I was trying to query the objects in apex and wanted to show them in the picklist, but it is returning all the objects. I have tried to ignore with the below logic, but it seems like I have to write a lot of code for this. Is there any better way to do this?

```
    for(Schema.SObjectType objTyp : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()){
            String name = objTyp.getDescribe().getName();
            if(!name.containsignorecase('history') && !name.containsignorecase('tag')&& !name.containsignorecase('share') && !name.containsignorecase('feed')&& !name.containsignorecase('status')&& !name.containsignorecase('priority')&& !name.containsignorecase('repository')&& !name.containsignorecase('partner')){
              SobjectList.add(name);
    }
}
SObjectList.sort();
return SObjectList;
```

Comment: Just what objects are you actually trying to include? Standard CRM objects and any custom objects? Just custom objects? Only those the user can create? Have you taken a look at the [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) methods, such as `isCustom` and others?

Comment: I want to include all the custom objects and some standard objects such as Account, Contact, Product and Order

Comment: If you have an explicit list of the standard objects, you can then use `isCustom` to find the rest...

Comment: I do not have explicit list of standard objects what I am trying to do is querying the objects and trying to ignore all the system objects and other standard objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to list the standard objects that are of interest, you can get these and all the custom objects using something like:

```
Set<String> standard = new Set<String> { 'Account', 'Contact', 'Product', 'Order' };

List<String> sobjectList = new List<String>();

for (Schema.SObjectType objTyp : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()){
    DescribeSObjectResult describe = objTyp.getDescribe();

    if (standard.contains(describe.getName()) ||
        describe.isCustom()) {
        sobjectList.add(describe.getName());
    }
}

sobjectList.sort();

return sobjectList;
```

If this isn't quite enough, check the other methods on [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) to see if these will help you filter out what you don't want (or select what you do want).

Comment: Getting error on this line standard.containsignorecase(describe.getName()) stating "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void containsignorecase(String) from the type Set<String>"

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to remove the case check when copying your code. Sorted in a previous edit.

Comment: I am not able to understand this line sobjectList.add(name); I mean there is no instance of name

Comment: Sorry, more copy/paste mistakes.

Comment: :D Thanks! it finally worked